# mounting problem during installation of archlinux on dell xps one

Tags: shell, arch-linux, mount, system-installation

I've been trying to install archlinux on xps one. 
the screen doesn't work because it has intel g45/g43 express chipset.
I had to use `nomodeset` option as mentioned in [the installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Troubleshooting_boot_problems).
Arch somewhat booted but i get an error:

```
:: Mounting '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212' to '/run/archiso/bootmnt'
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212 ...
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212' device not show up after 30 seconds.
..
   Falling back to interactive prompt
   You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when  you are finished
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
(had to write it by hand)
```

none off the commands in the installation manual worked. including `parted` and `fdisk`. the commands are just missing.
the interesting thing is that archbang booted.

My main question is how do i get into arch's installation environmental so i have commands like `parted`.

It might help me if I can find out what environment i'm in. for example, `less`, `mount` works but `more` doesn't.

PS: i tried to post it on arch forums but the registration process is broken.

**Update (1)**
i tried to chroot https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux#Method_2:_Chroot_into_LiveCD-image but

```
sh: unaquashfs: not found
```

**Update (2)**
if during boot menu. i prress `Tab`, i get:

```
> /linux boot/x86_64/vmlinuz archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201212 initrd=boot/x86_64/archiso.img
```

to get to command prompt, i have to add `nomodeset`

Comment: The commands don't work because it can't find your installation medium and falls back to a ramdisk. Did you change the install medium's filesystem label?

Comment: @ChrisDown no, didn't change anything. i'm not sure where i cal look it up

Comment: @ChrisDown Is there any place where I can find out what correct labels I should use?

Comment: How did you create the installation medium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check this post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142473

They mention something about specifying the wrong device when creating the disk. In particular, maybe you used /dev/sdx1 instead of /dev/sdx

If that doesn't help, I suggest you try the two options to create the live USB they give in their wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Installation_Media

Then, if it keeps failing, try Unetbootin to generate the bootable USB.

If you still can't make it work, try either using ArchBang (fastest option), the Netboot image, or an older snapshot of Arch (not too old, or it won't have systemd).

Finally, if all of the above failed, cry yourself to sleep and install another distribution when you wake up :)

Comment: thanks for the informative answer. makes sense. for now i chose the last option and got vista. at some point i'll try to dual-boot arch .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this'll work, since Arch shouldn't have any problem with this. But if you created your USB key under Windows (it may happen on other OSs as well, I don't know), its name may be shorter that the one Arch is seeking.

For example, when I tried to install Architect, the boot process expected the name to be `architect-201601-64bit`, while Windows named it `ARCHITECT-2`.

I'm saying you shouldn't have any problem with Arch because this shouldn't happen, since `ARCH_201212` is way shorter.

First you probably want to try a `ls /dev/disk/by-label/` to check the key name. If its name is different, just do the command `mv /dev/disk/by-label/<key name> /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212` (replace by your version name obviously). Then type `exit`, and the boot process goes on just fine.

Finally, I might add that it might not be a problem anymore, since the question was asked 3 years ago. But if this issue still happens, I'd rather post this in case it actually helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the observed problem is explained here:
https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/713#issuecomment-196901835

This is present all over the linux eco-system. They lack understanding of how things work (in this case FAT filesystem), but they find one single way to make it work (using Rufus or other software that would fix their mess on-the-fly).