# Problems installing Arch Linux: cannot mount the installation media

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mounting problem during installation of archlinux on dell xps one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58344/mounting-problem-during-installation-of-archlinux-on-dell-xps-one)

I am trying to install Arch Linux on my Acer Aspire 4830tg, but I keep running into problems. I am trying to install Arch off a USB stick and I got the iso image using Bittorrent. I am also trying to install it alongside of Windows 8 (which is already installed).
When I boot into Arch linux I get this error

```
:: Mounting '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212' to 'run/archiso/bootmnt'
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212 ...
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212' device did not show up after 30 seconds...
Falling back to interactive prompt
You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

So I know that it will work if I run it on a virtual machine but whenever I try to install it on my laptop I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The boot process isn't finding your usb stick. Probably it isn't labeled in the way its initscript expects. Are you sure the iso you burned to the stick is a (hybrid) iso intended to be used for usb sticks? Are you sure you burned it following published directions?

In the interactive prompt, you should be able to do a `ls /dev/disk/by-label/` to see if any labeled devices are showing up. If `ls` isn't available, try instead: `echo /dev/disk/by-label/*`. The information you get in this way may suggest a work-around. But I expect that you'll want/need to fix whatever earlier issue is causing the divergence between the way your usb stick looks and what the Arch boot/init/installation scripts are expecting to see.

(Warning: Your question is probably "too localized" for this site and will probably be closed.)