# archlinux installation failing mounting issue

Tags: arch-linux, mount, system-installation

I can boot to my CD created using ubuntu. I boot to the archlinux x86-64 and it boots me into [rootfs /]#
The error I am getting is the same error I am seeing in a lot of forums.
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512' device did not show up after 30 seconds...

I have checked the label of the cd created it is correct. 
I have looked to try and find the folder by-label it does not exist.
so by looking at several other forums primarily this one
[mounting problem during installation of archlinux on dell xps one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58344/mounting-problem-during-installation-of-archlinux-on-dell-xps-one)
and
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142473
I have tried various combinations of the following commands to fix.

cd /dev
ln -s sr0 archiso
exit

this yielded same error

udevadm trigger
which yielded different possible errors
754.659428 blk_update_request:I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1357824
754.792750 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1357824
754.794155 Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 169728, async page read

Ive never used ubuntu before to write a cd so maybe IT is the problem.

arcisodevice=/dev/sr0
exit
yielded the first error of ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512' device did not show up after 30 seconds...

What I am finding by running
ls /dev/disk
is by-id   by-path  by-uuid
the by-label folder does not exist????

I have tried mv /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512 /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512 which yielded error of does not exist because the folder by-label does not exist I know that this command would have done nothing.

cd /dev
ln -s sr0 /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512
yielding no such file or directory
so ...
mkdir /dev/disk/by-label
ln -s sr0 /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512
exit
no activity on drive and yielded same error
I am going to remake the cd because of the I?O errors and will update.
Any help here is appreciated. Haven't touched linux for ten years relearning alot.....

I made another cd using ubuntu using burnproof and I still see the same errors.
grrr.... help ....

Next I will try the following... https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux

Answer (score 1):

Make the path first if it doesn't exist, perhaps you renamed the label before starting Arch Linux:

`mkdir -p /dev/disk/by-label/`

This makes a directory, including it's parents given the path provided.

`ln -s <actual disk path> /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512`

This creates a symbolic link from the `/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201512` to the `<actual disk path>` that the live image is looking for.

The file that needs to be linked is `/dev/sr0` which is evident since I started a VM with Arch Linux boot media.

Lastly: Type `exit` to have the live image check for the path again. Then you should be ready to continue with installation.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to Necro this post. But, I have been searching for HOURS trying to find a fix for this, and I just wanted to post my thanks. Maybe others will find this useful as well. Bradley Kennedy's answer worked wonderfully.

I was trying to load into FWUL (Forget Windows Use Linux) from a LIVE DVD that I burned with Windows 10 using imgBurn. I tried all of the different fixes I could find. This worked beautifully.

Tab to edit after GRUB loads.

```
mkdir -p /dev/disk/by-label/
ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/disk/by-label/FWUL
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution for me! I was having trouble installing Manjaro, but aside from changing FWUL to what it was looking for, this was exactly what I needed.